# Cant seem to run aws cdk command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I just re-installed aws cdk and when i run `cdk synth` I am getting this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:4920
          } catch {
                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.js:3:15)
```

Comment: yeah, changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing my node version to 16.16.0